# am I allowed to choose epsilon in this way in cauchy sequence?

Tags: calculus, limits, cauchy-sequences

Its given that $a_{n+1}-a_{n} >= \frac{1}{n}$ 
We need to show that $a_{n}$ goes for infinity,
My solution: from the given we conclude $a_{n}$ is monotonic,lets assume $a_{n}$ is bounded then it converges to $L$, a sequence converges iff its cauchy sequence thus it must satisfy that
$\vert a_{n+p}-a_{n}\vert \leq \epsilon $

For $p=1$, $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ we get that it cant be a cauchy sequence according to the first given
Thus it's not bounded thus it goes to infinity

My question is: am I allowed to choose epsilon to be $\frac{1}{n}$, is my solution valid?

Thanks

Comment: A proof that $a_n \to \infty$ is a proof that the harmonic series diverges, and so cannot be that simple (thought it's not very hard either).

Comment: You missed whats given, the sign bigger wasnt there

Comment: $n$ varies, so you cannot choose $\epsilon =\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Hey, I didnt clearly understand you, what you mean by varies?

Comment: @TommyKad: Is not $\epsilon$ supposed to be a fixed positive number. In the definition of Cauchy Sequence when we write for 'arbitray epsilon', we mean whatever epsilon you choose, you are going to get a natural number such that blah blah happens. That is you can choose your epsilon whatever you want, but once you have chosen it is fixed. Now if you say $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$, then what is your $\epsilon$?    $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{50}, \frac{1}{1468}$, what is it? Does this make things clearer?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a new epsilon for every new n when n goes to infinity.

$a_{n+1}>a_n+1/n >a_{n-1}+1/(n-1)+1/n>…>a_1+H(n)$ where H(n) is the sum of the harmonic series. You might then need to prove that this series diverges. That proof is easier to find, e.g. on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The $\epsilon$ we use is termed "arbitrary", that is, it does not depend on anything. Here your $\epsilon$ depends on $n$, so it is not feasible.

However for this proof, I can give you a hint:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n \ge \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n) \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $$

The R.H.S. of inequality is divergent. Can you use comparison test now?